# Is there any name of matrix that sub matrix is circulant matrix?

Tags: matrices, coding-theory, block-matrices, circulant-matrices

I have studied [low-density parity-check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-density_parity-check_code) (LDPC) codes, which use quasi-cyclic codes whose submatrices are cyclic shifts of the identity matrix or of the zero matrix. For example,

[image: 802.11 standard]

Each number means: $-1$ is all zero matrix, if not $-1$ it is shift amount.

I need mathematical theory about this kind of matrix, but I can't find any theory when I search about quasi-cyclic LDPC, cyclic matrix , circulant matrix. So, if anyone know name of this kind of matrix, please tell me.

Comment: What is LDPC ?...

Comment: A it is kind of error correcting code that used in communication or storage.

Comment: Sub-matrices are usually shifted identity matrix.

Comment: I have learned some coding theory, and I understood nothing of your question. Please consider clarifying it.

Comment: What i want to know is, there is mathematical area that study about matrix that consist of circulant sub-matrix. but I found paper that what i want to know finally.